# Questions have yellow background?

Tags: discussion, design, questions

I am curious - why certain questions have light-yellow backgrounds? (for example as in this [screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/q0ePSSRmBWd5) from SharePoint SE home page). What is so special about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mapping your Watched tags. Yellow is highlighted for tags you added as watched tags.

[image]

Comment: Ou nice. Thank you.